# Extract values from SQL Query String

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a sql query string, I want to extract all the critical information from the string, for eg; table name, filters, limit, etc.

`const sql = select * from products where id=1 and description like '%thick and crispy%'`;

```
const filters = [
"id=1",
"description like '%thick and crispy%'"
];
```

My first thought is to use Regex, and split the string at `where`,`and` clause.

```
const filters = sql.split(/ and /gi);
```

ps: Regex shown is only for understanding.

And, this would work fine for most the cases, until the values itself doesn't contain these regex search terms.
In above example, if you see, description value itself contains `and`  word. This would cause the string getting splitted at unexpected place.

Is there any better way to handle this problem with Regex or javascript?

**ps:** SQL queries are generally case insensitive, so we can't split by minding the case sensitivity. The sql Query shown above is provided by users, for which, we can't control the case sensitivity in a certain manner.

**Note**: I've kept the example easy to keep it understandable. But in live environment, we need to watch all possible clauses: LIKE, OR, AND, IN, etc., and there can be multiple AND, OR filters provided in the query string.

Comment: Do you need this parser as part of a project you work on? If yes, use your favourite search engine and take one of the existing solutions. Do you want to write a parser just for fun? Get familiar with terms like contextfree grammar, tokenizer, lexer, parser, abstract syntax tree ... SQL is a very powerful and complicated language. Regular expressions are not even remotely capable of parsing it unless you cripple it down to (more or less unusable) bar minimum.

Comment: You noticed yourself the problem with keywords appearing as conditions. For that you have to be able to recognize stringsvalues and pairs of quotation marks, Quite hard with regex. There can be nested parenthesis. Absolutely impossible with regular expressions (letting aside some obscure extensions like recursive patters which are available in some languages)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @derpirscher. For the current requirement, readymade parsers sounds good. I'll look around for the same. Though I'm curious about the terms you mentioned, will check them out.